# What do I have to to when it says: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'"?

Tags: python, list

I was doing a Codecademy Challenge when I came across the problem that following message was appearing when I wanted to check my answer:  `estimate_insurance_cost.append(("Maria", maria_insurance_cost)) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
def estimate_insurance_cost(name, age, sex, bmi, num_of_children, smoker):
  estimated_cost = 250*age - 128*sex + 370*bmi + 425*num_of_children + 24000*smoker - 12500
  print(name + "'s Estimated Insurance Cost: " + str(estimated_cost) + " dollars.")
  return estimated_cost
 
# Estimate Maria's insurance cost
maria_insurance_cost = estimate_insurance_cost(name = "Maria", age = 31, sex = 0, bmi = 23.1, num_of_children = 1, smoker = 0)

# Estimate Rohan's insurance cost
rohan_insurance_cost = estimate_insurance_cost(name = 
"Rohan", age = 25, sex = 1, bmi = 28.5, num_of_children = 3, smoker = 0)

# Estimate Valentina's insurance cost
valentina_insurance_cost = estimate_insurance_cost(name = "Valentina", age = 53, sex = 0, bmi = 31.4, num_of_children = 0, smoker = 1)


names = ["Maria", "Rohan", "Valentina"]
insurance_costs = ["4150.0", "5320.0", "35210.0"]
insurance_data = zip(names, insurance_costs)
print(insurance_data)
insurance_data = list(zip(names, insurance_costs))
print(insurance_data)

estimate_insurance_cost.append(("Maria", maria_insurance_cost))
estimate_insurance_cost.append(("Rohan", rohan_insurance_cost))
estimate_insurance_cost.append(("Valentina", valentina_insurance_cost))
print(estimate_insurance_cost)
```

Comment: your list is `insurance_data `, `estimate_insurance_cost` is your function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a list (or dictionary, maybe?) of estimated insurance costs, but you're giving it the same name as your function, and you also haven't explicitly declared it as anything other than a function.

Here's how you'd create a dictionary called `estimated_costs` with this information:

```
estimated_costs = {
    "Maria": maria_insurance_cost,
    "Rohan": rohan_insurance_cost,
    "Valentina": valentina_insurance_cost,
}
```

Comment: Thank you, bro! Started just one week ago, appreciate the fast advice from that community!